# How to search word inside single line using regular expression

Tags: visual-studio, regex

```
string patname ="enter pat name";
patname = "text";
patname = " text pat";
```

Hi, I want to search "pat" in the above statement using regular expression of visual studio. I tried using `Pat{([^a-zA-Z]|$)}` this , but it will also search the 2nd line which i really don't want. I want pat to be search inside a string value which starts from " follwoed by any char and then "pat". I mean pat can come anywhere ,i.e. either in start,middle or end.

does somebody hav idea how to do tht?

Comment: Code such as [string s = "some text " + patname + " other text";] will cause you problems also, as a simple regex will find " + patname + " and return true

Answer (score 2):

So you want to look for "pat" in a string in your source code? There are some issues with that... in particular:

1: handling the quotes is awkward (to separate the literal part of the string as opposed to variables etc) - especially with 2 types of escaping; @"""" and "\""

2: in a verbatim string literal, pat could be on the next line but still in the string:

```
string s = @"abc
def pat ghi";
```

However, for a **rough** search, something like:

```
\".+pat
```

may help

Answer (score 0):

should be something like:

```
/.*pat.*/
```

which . indicates wild char in regex, and .* means any number of occurence of any character

Answer (score 0):

How about using word boundaries?

In Visual Studio:

```
<pat>
```

Re-reading your question you'll only want the 'pat' inside a string so

```
"[^"]*<pat>[^"]*"
```

is probably a better expression.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly regex you are looking for is just simply

```
\".+\bpat\b
```

If you want whole line to be found use

```
.*\".+\bpat\b.*
```

To clarify: `\b`'s mean word boundaries. If you want 'pat' to be a part of a word remove them.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work , i need to search pat inside a string value so i think search shud start somethign like \"[a-z][pat], but the problem is tht it doesn't seach the pat inside ("enter pat name")

Comment: Why should it? \"[a-z][pat] means "quote followed by a single alpha, followed by any one of p/a/t". Which isn't what you mean, and isn't what you asked for in the original question. It also isn't clear which it" you are referring to here..

Answer (score 0):

Try `"[:a ]*<pat>[:a ]*"`.